# библиотеки и PyCharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

При установке библиотеки Flask, PyCharm пишет, что такой библиотеки не существует. Как быть?
ошибка:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'

На удивление pip3 install Flask не помогает. При повторной установке пишет, что библиотека уже существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках PyCharm нужно было установить системный интерпретатор, то есть Python, который устанавливался вручную, а не через PyCharm. И сделать также для самого файла.

---

PS после выбора системного интерпретатора можно будет увидеть доступные для обработки библиотеки.

Comment: Или в настройках оставить интерпретатор из виртуального окружения, и все библиотеки ставить в это виртуальное окружение (например, через терминал в PyCharm, или активировать это окружение в командной строке самостоятельно, и ставить все в него). Рекомендую почитать про виртуальные окружения. Бонус их использования с PyCharm - он не так долго будет индексировать установленные пакеты.